# How to Track Calls, SMS and Text in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way I can track Calls, Emails, SMS and Contacts in WP7. I specifically need to know when the recent call is ended or any notification that my application can get when call ends with details of the call.  Or can I fetch the Call history when the my app starts. Can I do the same for Email, SMS and Contacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You have several barriers to what you are trying to do.

- Currently, third party apps can't run in the background to be notified of the events you mentioned.
- Third party apps are not allowed to access call history.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot do this with the current version of SDK. May be they will add it in future versions. 2 of which are set to be released this year.